# What's the term for the coefficient that change any floating point number to its next or previous value?

Tags: terminology, floating-point

I calculated that the following two coefficients will reduce any finite floating point number to its next exact lower value:

Single precision: `0.99999994`

Double precision: `0.99999999999999989`

This means it reduces the number to the next lower number that can be stored in the applicable FP format. It does so for any value.

Is there a technical term for these coefficients?

Comment: Probably something involving terms like "Machine precision" or "Machine Epsilon"...  It doesn't seem very useful in either event.  If you want to decrease to the next value, just subtract by the smallest value possible instead of multiply by your values.  Subtraction is far less costly and the code would be easier to read and understand.

Comment: Subtracting by a constant won't work across the entire range of valid numbers. The coefficient works perfectly. "Machine epsilon" seems to have a similar meaning, but it's on the one end of the scale only.

Comment: As an aside, subtraction and multiplication are both 4 clock cycles on modern x64 and most Arm CPUs.

Comment: What do you mean with "the coefficients will reduce ..." ? You did not say what you do with this coefficients. And what does "next exact lower value" mean ? Please be more precise !

Comment: @Peter, it reduces the number to the next lowest number that can be stored in the applicable FP format. It does so for any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a term for this constant because it doesn't exist: You *can't* perform this operation with a multiplication by a constant.  For example, consider the double-precision numbers:

- $a = 1$
- $b = 1 + 2^{-52} \approx 1.000000000000000222044604925$
- $c = 2 - 2^{-51} \approx 1.999999999999999555910790150$
- $d = 2 - 2^{-52} \approx 1.999999999999999777955395075$

Then $a$ and $b$ form a pair of consecutive floating-point numbers, as do $c$ and $d$.  But the ratios are different:

- $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{2^{52}}{2^{52} + 1} \approx 0.9999999999999997779553950750$
- $\frac{c}{d} = \frac{2^{53}-2}{2^{53}-1} \approx 0.9999999999999998889776975375$

These don't even round to the same `double` value, as the former gets represented as $1 - 2^{-52}$, and the latter gets represented as $1-2^{-53}$.

As for related terminology, the next/previous values are conventionally called “successor” and “predecessor”, and the smallest number $x$ such that $1 + x \ne 1$ in floating-point arithmetic is called [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).